# Fingerprint sensor not working on Lenovo Ideapad Slim 5 + Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, fingerprint-reader, ideapad

I recently bought a Lenovo Ideapad Slim 5 and got Ubuntu 22.04 on it (bought it without OS, didn't want Windows).

I have tried getting the fingerprint sensor to work but it seems that it can't even be found using lsusb.
Obviously the normal path Users -> Fingerprint lock is not available.

The fprint doesn't work on this ubuntu anymore, I've authorized it through Pam-auth but it still doesn't show anything.
I even went through BIOS to see if it's enabled but there doesn't seem to be a reason for it to not work.
If any of you could help it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you are not alone with this problem. There seem to be many laptops with built-in fingerprint readers not recognized by linux. As far as I have understood this is of course again due to lack of driver support. There are way to many vendors of cheap parts like fingerprint sensors and driver support seems to be expensive...

One way of at least trying to get around this is to retrieve HW-infos for the community so maybe some really nice person can develop a driver...

You can do this by installing hw-probe from linux-hardware.org
(https://linux-hardware.org/?view=howto)

Before, check, if this is already done for your laptop
https://linux-hardware.org/?view=computers&vendor=Lenovo&model=IdeaPad+Slim+5+%28All%29

Hope, this helps